# How to properly set keydown event listener to send message?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, event-handling, use-effect

I am writing a small **chat app** and I ran up into some difficulties. App is properly working but I want to set `keydown` event listener to track when user presses *Enter* so he can also send message this way (not just manually clicking the *Send message* button).

I am using **Firebase** and **firestore** as a DB to save messages. Here is the full code of *Chat.jsx* component:

```
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'
import { FirebaseContext } from '..'
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import Loader from './loader/Loader'
import { generateRandomKey } from '../helpers/generateRandomKey'

const Chat = () => {
    const { auth, firestore } = useContext(FirebaseContext)

    const [user] = useAuthState(auth)
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const [messages, loading] = useCollectionData(
        firestore.collection('messages').orderBy('createdAt')
    )

    const handleSendMessage = async () => {
        firestore.collection('messages').add({
            uid: user.uid,
            displayName: user.displayName,
            photoURL: user.photoURL,
            text: value,
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        })
        setValue('')
    } // useCallback?

    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                handleSendMessage()
            }
        })
        return () =>
            document.body.removeEventListener('keydown', e => {
                if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                    handleSendMessage()
                }
            })
    }, []) // what to put in deps?

    if (loading) return <Loader />

    return (
        <div className="content">
            <div>
                {messages.map(message => {
                    return (
                        <div key={generateRandomKey()}>
                            <div>
                                <img
                                    src={message.photoURL}
                                    alt="User avatar"
                                />
                                <p>{message.displayName}</p>
                            </div>
                            <p>{message.text}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                    placeholder="Enter your message..."
                    value={value}
                    onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
                ></input>
                <button onClick={handleSendMessage}>Send message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

**Speaking about problems** - when I am trying to set event listener via `useEffect` with `handleMessage` dependency whenever I press *Enter* it sends two empty messages and then a couple of messages like this:

`message: 'hello' -> '' - '' - 'h' - 'he' - 'hel' - 'hell' - 'hello'`

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            handleSendMessage()
        }
    })
    return () =>
        document.body.removeEventListener('keydown', e => {
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                handleSendMessage()
            }
        })
}, [handleSendMessage])
```

Same happens if I wrap `handleSendMessage` with `useCallback` hook and put `[user, value, firestore]` in deps.

**Question:** How can I fix this and properly set `keydown` event listener to send messages via pressing *Enter*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accidentally solved this problem. I was thinking in a wrong way trying to set `keydown` event listener in `useEffect` hook.

All I had to do is to set custom event in `<input />` element like this:

```
<input
    placeholder="Enter your message..."
    value={value}
    onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} //this one
/>
```

And then add a handler:

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        if (value) {
            handleSendMessage()
        }   
    }
}
```

Now everything's working just fine and I can finally send messages by pressing *Enter* key without any side-effects!